# Setting up Heroku CLI in WSL

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, heroku

Trying to setup Heroku CLI to work with WSL.

Starting by following the directions here for Ubuntu 16+:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

`sudo snap install --classic heroku`

Produces the following error:

> error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/heroku: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Googled the error and came across this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1631514

I tried `systemctl status snapd.service`, which just says the following:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

Restart WSL and the computer and same issue.

Thought maybe `snapd` wasn't installed because typing `snap` or `snapd` says `Command '____' not found, did you mean:...`. But trying to do `sudo apt-get install snapd` says that it is already the latest version.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope, doesn't sound like there is current support in WSL for `snap`. `snapd`, nor `systemd`. Thankfully there is a manual install provided by Heroku, so will give that a shot.

This worked in my case:

`curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh`

Comment: Do note that _sudo_ applies to individual commands, not to the whole pipeline. `curl | sudo sh` makes sense (if a bit dangerous), `sudo curl | sh` is useless.

Comment: No superuser permissions required, tested on WSL and working fine.

Comment: Mine just asked for credentials where needed :) You probably set up a password or choose to omit it when you first set up WSL I imagine. At the end of the install though it did complain about: `[EACCES] Error Plugin: heroku: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/coder/.cache/heroku'`

Comment: I ended up having to run the following to get the heroku cli happy and not throwing those errors I listed in my last comment: `sudo chmod -R 0777 ~/.cache/heroku`

Comment: On WSL2 I get the following error: gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed

Comment: @user26631 i ran into the same issue and have added an answer with how i got it to work, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great solution, and requires context switching, but you can install the Heroku cli in Windows and do your pushes/Heroku cli interactions from the Windows interface.

Answer (score 0):

voted answer did work but first had to do the following

first enable `virtual machine platform`

[image]

then had to update default version for wsl by running the following in ps (for me was in ps 7)

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

then i was able to run the following in ubuntu `bash`

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

and all works so far